# woocommerce hook delete product from the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

what are you doing for it?
i wrote this string in the end of file (wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 'wordpress_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 10, 1);

function wordpress_before_cart_item_quantity_zero($item) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart = $woocommerce->cart;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $id_product = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM wp_block_product WHERE product_id = %d", $id_product);
        $preparing_query = $wpdb->query($preparing_query);
    }

    var_dump($wpdb);
    exit;
}
```

but when i delete item from the cart it's not working!

i was try do so:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 'wordpress_before_cart_item_quantity_zero');
```

but it's not working too

Answer (score 4):

According to [the source](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#974), you're looking for `'woocommerce_cart_item_removed'`, which runs when an item is removed from the cart:

```
function so31115243_after_remove_product($cart_item_key) {
    // Your custom function
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'so31115243_after_remove_product' );
```

Comment: I have question:
Why $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() returned me empty array when i have one item in the cart?

Comment: @DanyaAndreew Hook runs after the item is removed from the cart!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a hook that runs before removing the item, which is `woocommerce_remove_cart_item`.

I believe that is what Danya is looking for in the comment above in case anyone runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

@rnevius solution works but need to change the priority of the action. For me it was 21 but i think it can change regarding plugins using this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'so31115243_after_remove_product', 21 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function so_27030769_maybe_empty_cart() {

global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation_custom', 'so_27030769_maybe_empty_cart', 10, 3 );
// Usage
apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation_custom','','');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).